# Linux: Set up a temporary FTP storage without adding a user to the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-16.04

I want to receive a folder containing 10GB+ of data from someone. We cannot see each other, and our internet speed is too slow, but we both are in the same LAN (100Mbps).

Therefore, I want to **temporarily set up an FTP server** on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and define a temporary username so that he can connect to it and upload the files into the server (i.e. my machine).

**It seems that vsftpd is not a proper solution, as it allows access to local users only (is it true?). I do not want to add a user to my Linux machine. Instead, I just want to add a temporary user to ftp server only.**

What is the best solution?

P.S. FileZilla is the only software that the sender can use! Do not suggest alternative options such as SSH, etc.

Comment: If you configure the ftp server to allow anonymous uploading you wouldn't need to add a user, but perhaps you'd be opposed to that as well.  Would you be more willing to create a local user account if you set it to not be permitted to login with a shell?

Comment: For this case just go and buy a USB-Key. It's a workaround but probably faster than setting all this up. How would your internet speed matter if you're both on the same LAN and what do you mean by you can't see each other? If the hosts are isolated you won't be able to connect.

Comment: For the record: there is no conflict between mandatory FileZilla and SSH because FileZilla supports SCP.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  The point is that I do not want to let him access via ssh or have a user-directory on my machine. For security reasons...

Comment: @EricRenouf The point is that I do not want to let him access via ssh or have a user-directory on my machine. For security reasons...

Comment: @Seth I cannot reach him for some reason. We are just in the same high-speed LAN (intranet)

Comment: You can create users on the system who do not have a home directory and cannot login via ssh (or the console).

Comment: What do you mean by "you can not reach him"? In a physical sense or on a network level? For the first case you could use a IRL mail and for the second one you would have to elaborate what works and doesn't work. Afterall it could mean he wouldn't be able to access your FTP anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/) can do this using [VirtualUser](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/VirtualUsers.html). The VirtualUser is a user that is known only to ProFTPD and does not have any connection with the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

vsftpd is the proper way to go, it should only be combined with pam_userdb to achieve virtual users you may then map however you like.